# Does Spring.io contains the packages of Hibernate? or I need to download some zip files for hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have finished learning Spring Boot from a tutorialspoint, my second learning path is Hibernate. They have mentioned that I need to download Hibernate package and then set CLASSPATH for it in order for its proper working.

My question is, does Spring.io contains Hibernate packages already? Or do I need to download Hibernate and set CLASSPATH manually?

Comment: type jpa, you will get hibernate, and then make sure to type your db name. for oracle-mysql type mysql, for mariadb type maria-db, or any other data storage

Comment: spring-data-jpa dependency doing it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download anything by your own.

https://start.spring.io/ uses Maven or Gradle as build tool and this contains the dependency management that will download the packages for you.

When you build the application the Spring Boot plugin will create an executable JAR where all the dependencies are included.

Comment: Got it. it worked.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept it. Thank you

Comment: Hey, can you tell me the "Accepting answers" term in stackoverflow? I am not quite getting that. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hey, 
I did accepted your answer but got 
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Also, accept my questions, like as my reputation is low.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to **Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or this one for **Gradle**

```
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

**This dependency includes JPA API, JPA Implementation, JDBC, and other needed libraries.**

You can of course exclude the `Hibernate` dependency from the `spring-boot-starter` and import the dependency yourself (your preferred version) as:

**For Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**For Gradle:**

```
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
   exclude group: "org.hibernate", module: "hibernate-core"
}
implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.0.Final"
```

*Please note that in order to use a database you must provide the Database driver, for instance, the `H2` in-memory database:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Perfect. Understood. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I hoped it helped :) You can accept the answer if it was helpful or if it solves your issue.

Comment: Also, accept my questions, like as my reputation is low.
thanks.